# C Programming; Word, Character and Line Count K&R 1-11

Tags: c, word-count, line-count, charactercount

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define YES 0
#define NO 0

int main()
{
    int c, nl, nc, nw, tab;

    nl = 0;
    nc = 0;
    nw = 0;

    tab = NO;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        ++nc;
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')
            tab = NO;
        else if (tab == NO) 
        {
            tab = YES;
            ++nw;
        }
    }
    printf("NL: %d\nNC: %d\nNW: %d\n", nl, nc, nw);
}
```

Hey guys, new coder here. Actually, very much new, I just started a few days ago in hopes of broadening my job opportunities. Anyway, with this program, it counts every new line, word and character. For the most part, I understand what is going on but what I don't understand is the new word part. For example, at the top where we #define YES/NO, the number proceeding the word apparently does not matter? I swapped out 1 and 0 for so many other choices and yet still received the same outcome, why is that? Apologies in advance if this is a dumb question, for I myself am a dumb coder. Take care and thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Previous point:**

In C a conditional expression will evaluate to false if it is `0` and true if it is any other value, so `YES` can be `1`, `1000`, `-1000`, etc., as long as it is not `0` the conditional expression where it's evaluated will always be true.

**As for the question:**

For the code to work as expected `YES` must be `1`, or, as per the explanation above, not `0`.

In

```
else if (tab == NO) 
{
    tab = YES;
    ++nw;
}
```

If `YES` is `0`, `tab` will always be `0` and `NW` will not be accurate because it will count all the characters except if they are `\t`,   or `\n` and this is not what program should do, `NW` should be the number of words.

For instance, for this input:

```
This is a word I wrote
```

You'll have:

```
NL: 1
NC: 23
NW: 17
```

When it should be:

```
NL: 1
NC: 23
NW: 6
```

Setting `tab` to `1` (`YES`) serves as a flag to signal that piece of code to only increment `nw` 1 time in case there is one of those three charaters thus counting the spaces between the words or the newline character ***one time only***, giving you the number of words in the inputed text.

Comment: Well said, thank you so much. Can't believe I missed that!

Comment: @haiphan0445, glad to help a fellow new programmer ;) note that you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/684852) if you feel it solved your problem.

Comment: Heard! I'll definitely be around and asking more questions, hope to see you around. Thank you again Ana

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to this wolrd!you dont need it. I think this should be the right way(I am sorry for my english and my poor explanations):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c, nl, nc, nw;

    nl = 0;
    nc = 0;
    nw = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        ++nc;
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
        if (c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n')
            ++nw;
    }
    printf("NL: %d\nNC: %d\nNW: %d\n", nl, nc, nw);
}
```